# Changing the value of tuple inside a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

How do I change the **second value** of the **first tuple** in the **first list** by force??

```
test_list=[[(12, 5), (13, 6)], [(12, 2), (13, 2)]]
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable.  You would need to replace it instead.

Since lists are mutable, you would replace the first element of the first list with a new tuple having a changed second value.

```
test_list = [[(12, 5), (13, 6)], [(12, 2), (13, 2)]] 

# test_list - unchanged
# test_list[0] - modified
# test_list[0][0] - replaced
# test_list[0][0][0] - preserved
# test_list[0][0]1] - new
new_second_value = 'foobar'
new_value = (test_list[0][0][0], new_second_value)
test_list[0][0] = new_value
```

This would give you:

```
>>> test_list
[[(12, 'foobar'), (13, 6)], [(12, 2), (13, 2)]]
```

To do it in one line:

```
test_list[0][0] = (test_list[0][0][0], 'foobar')
```

Note that if you were using named tuples, you could simplify this slightly with a `._replace()` method (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace):

```
test_list[0][0] = test_list[0][0]._replace(foo='bar')
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what the output will be in the last line? I dont understand why you have given `foo='bar'`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm talking about https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace . 
 You are not using `namedtuple` in your example, but if you did it would simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable. You can not change the value of tuple.
To update the value you need to create a new tuple with updated value and then you can replace in the array.
[Tuples in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples)